# ERROR: requierd systempassword for user:postgres

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4, pgagent

hello at first i want install pageant in pgadmin4 so

i want to installed by application stack builder the issues it called

[here thee issues](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7X87.jpg)

there no option I see called system password for user

I try unstill and install the over again there's no change ..

Comment: Did you solve the problem? How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're having trouble using the Application Stack Builder to install Pageant in pgAdmin4. An error message requests the "system password for user: postgres." To start, try these:

**Run as Administrator:**
Start pgAdmin4 and the Stack Builder both in administrator mode.

**Password for PostgreSQL User:**
During installation, enter the password for the "postgres" user.

**Compatibility:**
Make sure your Pageant version is compatible with your PostgreSQL and pgAdmin4 versions.

**Disable Firewall and Antivirus:**
Turn them off momentarily while installing.

If the problem continues, download and install the components manually.