# pgAgent install on Windows error: "required systempassword for user:postgres"

Tags: postgresql, pgagent

I need job scheduling and this feature needs pgAgent installed along with postgresql (v15.4) via Stack builder (v4.2.1). But installation process fails with an error:

[image]

Things I have tried:

- Run Stack Builder as Administrator
- Reset postgres user password to "admin", "1234" and "12345"

More clues:

[image]

Looks like pgAgent is installed, but the directory is not present in `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL` or `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\15`

[image]

pgAgent service not exists however another similar service is installed!

PS: I already read [the other similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76911395) but it didn't help

Answer (score 0):

you'd need to download and install pgAdmin4 to make it easier to install pgAgent on your system, pgAdmin4 comes bundled with pgAgent installed so you don't necessarily have to go through the pain of manually installing that component, checkout https://www.pgadmin.org/download/pgadmin-4-windows/

Or, you could try going into the bin folder of your postgreSQL installation and type, `pgAgent INSTALL pgAgent -u windowsUser-p windowspassword hostaddr=127.0.0.1 dbaname=postgres user=postgres password=***` for a manual execution within your installation, although this is a quite hacky approach, I would suggest you to get pgAdmin4 installed rather as it's a MUCH smoother process.

Comment: Does installing pgAdmin4 also install pgAgent?  I installed pgAdmin4 and there is no pgAgent Service running in Windows, even after a restart.  I mainly want to run `psql` commands from the CLI and have the agent use the `pgpass.conf` file, but none of the pgAgent installation methods work.